# U3D model deactivates but does not go away! It remains in position on the next page when scrolling in singlepage mode (Acrobat Reader DC)

Tags: miktex, media9

I have come across a peculiar problem while using the `media9` package to include 3d models.

1. When I have an `\includemedia` followed by a `\newpage` and **two or more** `\includemedia` on the following page, the first `\includemedia` remains visible (but not active) on the next page. The `\includemedia` that should be on that page, draws over the one from the previous page. This only happens in singlepage mode (I think).
2. When there is a page (without models) in between, **there is no issue.**

Below is reduced code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final,activate=pageopen,deactivate=pageclose,noplaybutton]{media9}
\begin{document}
    \includemedia[
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        height=0.9\linewidth,
        3Dviews=Parts/91292A058/91292A058.vws
    ]{}{Parts/91292A058/91292A058.u3d}

    \newpage
    %Uncomment this line and next. No problems now.
    %\newpage

    \includemedia[
        width=0.3\linewidth,
        height=0.3\linewidth,
        3Dviews=Parts/91292A058/91292A058.vws
    ]{}{Parts/91292A058/91292A058.u3d}
    \includemedia[
        width=0.3\linewidth,
        height=0.3\linewidth,
        3Dviews=Parts/91292A058/91292A058.vws
    ]{}{Parts/91292A058/91292A058.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm this issue with AR-DC on Windows. It does not happen in older AR versions (e.g. AR-9 on Linux).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my problem @AlexG. Would it be possible for you to devise a solution for me? Perhaps a javascript that would deactivate the media after scrolling 2 pages?

Comment: I guess with `onclick` deactivation, a javascript could 'click' when page closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current AR-DC seems to have a bug which prevents automatic closing of RichMedia annotations on the page-close event.

This is a work-around which forces closing of 3D content by means of JavaScript:

(Open on [**->ShareLaTeX**](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/nfvphqxdvpjg)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final,activate=pageopen,noplaybutton]{media9}

% deactivate all RichMedia annots on the current page on page-close event
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr
    /AA <<
      /C <<
        /S/JavaScript /JS(
          var annotRichMedia=this.getAnnotsRichMedia(this.pageNum);
          for(var i=0; i<annotRichMedia.length; i++){
            annotRichMedia[i].activated=false;
          }
        )
      >>
    >>
  }
}
\x

\begin{document}

  \includemedia[%
      width=0.9\linewidth,
      height=0.9\linewidth,
      3Droo=27
  ]{}{dice.u3d}

  \newpage

  \includemedia[
      width=0.3\linewidth,
      height=0.3\linewidth,
      3Droo=27
  ]{}{dice.u3d}
  \includemedia[
      width=0.3\linewidth,
      height=0.3\linewidth,
      3Droo=27
  ]{}{dice.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexG! That worked great! Is this documented somewhere? I don't recall reading it in the media9 documentation...

Comment: The PDF Specification defines `/AA <<...>>`, the additional actions dictionary of the Page Object, `/C <<...>>` the action triggered by the Page-Close event, which is a JavaScript action here (`/S` means 'Subtype'). JavaScript for Acrobat is documented [**->here**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface%2FJS_API_AcroJSPreface.htm)

Comment: Nevertheless, the bug should be reported to  Adobe.

Comment: I reported the bug to adobe

Comment: I was scrolling quickly through a pdf (with more than 2 pages) and this workaround doesn't quite work. Is this another AR bug or a "feature" to speed up the viewer? (I think it is just not executing the JS at page close when scrolling past so quickly)

Comment: Also, I tried the `Save As` in AR-DC to see if it's "optimizing\linearizing" (or whatever it does to it) would help. This didn't fix it (but it made the file slightly smaller).

Comment: Another theory: Some media is not yet active, so page close script breaks (if deactivate order is not the order they are finished loading)

Comment: You are right. I extended te example on ShareLaTeX to ten pages. If I scroll very quickly in fullscreen mode, sometimes it happens that forced closing doesn't work. But switching one page back and forth at reasonable speed cures the scrambled display again. So it's still better than without the page-close JavaScript.

Comment: Definitely! Much much better than before